# State is empty even have setted up with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the data from the database and storing it in a state but when I console log my state, no data has been stored in the state but when I console the data itself, it returns what I expected to have. This is my code;

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Field, Form, Formik, useField } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {
    Button,
    Box,
    makeStyles,
    Grid,
    Typography,
    Divider,
    FormHelperText,
    Select,
    MenuItem,
    InputLabel,
    FormControl,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import {
    MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
    KeyboardDateTimePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import 'date-fns';

// Yup validation Schema
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    date: Yup.date().required('Please enter valid date').nullable(),
    teamOne: Yup.string().required('Please select team'),
    teamTwo: Yup.string().required('Please select team'),
});

// This is a custom date field using Formik
const DateTimeField = ({ field, form, ...props }) => {
    const currentError = form.errors[field.name];

    return (
        <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
            <KeyboardDateTimePicker
                clearable
                disablePast
                name={field.name}
                value={field.value}
                format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                helperText={currentError}
                error={!!currentError}
                onError={(error) => {
                    if (error !== currentError) {
                        form.setFieldError(field.name, error);
                    }
                }}
                onChange={(date) => form.setFieldValue(field.name, date, true)}
                {...props}
            />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
};

// Custom <Select> field
const TeamSelection = ({ name, ...props }) => {
const [field, meta] = useField(name);
const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : '';

return (
        <>
            <Select
                name={field.name}
                {...field}
                fullWidth
                error={!!errorText}
                {...props}
            >
                {props.children}
            </Select>
            <FormHelperText error>{errorText}</FormHelperText>
        </>
    );
};
    export default function AddMatch() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const fetchContext = useContext(FetchContext);
    const [team, setTeam] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getTeam = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('get-all-teams');
                setTeam(data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        getTeam();
    }, [fetchContext]);

    console.log(team);

    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ date: new Date(), teamOne: '', teamTwo: '' }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                if (values.teamOne === values.teamTwo) {
                    return console.log('Teams must not be the same!');
                }
                return console.log(values);
            }}
        >
            {() => (
                <Form noValidate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Typography>
                            Add Match
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Divider />
                    <Box>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Field
                                    name="date"
                                    label="Set date and time"
                                    component={DateTimeField}
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <FormControl>
                                        <InputLabel>
                                            Team A
                                        </InputLabel>
                                        <TeamSelection name="teamOne">
                                            <MenuItem value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</MenuItem>
                                            {team.map((item) => (
                                                <MenuItem value={item.teamName} key={item._id}>
                                                    {item.teamName}
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </TeamSelection>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid>
                                    <FormControl>
                                        <InputLabel>
                                            Team B
                                        </InputLabel>
                                        <TeamSelection name="teamTwo">
                                            <MenuItem value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</MenuItem>
                                            {team.map((item) => (
                                                <MenuItem value={item.teamName} key={item._id}>
                                                    {item.teamName}
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            ))}
                                        </TeamSelection>
                                    </FormControl>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                            <Box>
                                <Button type="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </Box>
                        </Grid>
                    </Box>
                </Form>
            )}
        </Formik>
    )}
```

I'm using Material UI and Formik.

It only logged an empty array "***[]***" or it makes an error, (**.map is not a function**). I tried to set the state as an Object but there is still no data being stored with the state.

Comment: Could you clean the code and put only the relevant parts? Without styles, Material, etc

Comment: As @pmiranda said, it would probably help if you removed parts of the code that are not relevant to your issue (such as the code related to the `useStyles` hooks).

`console.log` is a useful tool. However, it might be easier to leverage your browser dev tools. Chrome has a network tab in its dev tools where you can take a look at requests. Do you see your request to `get-all-teams` when you run your application?

Comment: `console.log(team);` team would not be guaranteed to display the latest state data as state setters are asynchronous. Try `useEffect(() => {console.log(team)}, [team])` to see the console log whenever `team` state data is changed.

Comment: @YvesGurcan It responded as status 200.

Comment: That's great to know! If you look at the payload of the response to the request in the network tab, does the data show up as expected or is it empty by any chance?

Comment: I have solved it already I have res.status(200).json({ data }), which should be res.status(200).json(data). To return an array. Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the post request in your res.status(200).json() or res.send() or res.json(). Don't use brackets inside .json() or .send(), in your res or response, for example:

```
.json({}) // Don't use brackets if you don't want to send your data as an Object
```

If ever you want it to be object, then call the array which is called data like

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getTeam = async () => {
            try {
                const { teamsData } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get('get-all-teams');
                setTeam(teamsData.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        getTeam();
    }, [fetchContext]);
```

destructure the teamsData if you have passed it as an Object on purpose.